# how can i apply kmeans algorithm on data from database and after use confusion matrix

Tags: python, database, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to apply a K Means algorithm on data from my database. First of all I am taking data like this:

[image: Image of my data]

So my questions are how I can make column with strings to numbers like "trash"=1, "car"=2  "truck"=3 and if I can use all columns and values for clustering.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to use label encoder of sklearn library

Comment: Thank you! I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

KMeans doesn't need "magic numbers".

It needs proper *continuous* variables, where the *mean* is meaningful. It's not the proper algorithm for your data. Minimizing least squares of encoded "dictionary numbers" is not sound.

Comment: Oh ok, I see. However, because I don't have experience on this do you have another algorithm to suggest for clustering my data? Thank you in advance. @Anony-Mousse

Comment: Hierarchical clustering.